# Manually mute sound in Android app when in silent mode?

Tags: android, audio

I have tried finding an answer to this, but my searches kept returning irrelevant results...
So the problem is - I am writing a game that plays sound effects (no music just yet), and I set the stream type to Music. However, when I put my phone in silent mode (no vibration either, if that matters)  the app still plays sounds. I can turn off the sound in the app using the volume keys, but what I expected (and what my future users would probably expect too) was that the app won't make a sound when the phone is in silent mode.

At this point, I am not sure if this should be automatically managed by the OS, or if I am expected to do something about it. I can surely detect the silent mode, set the volume to 0 in e.g `onResume`, but that will probably overwrite the setting the users set up by pressing the volume buttons - so when they unmute the phone, the app either has to set the volume programmatically to a predefined value, or ideally, to a saved one from sharedPrefs... which sounds relatively cumbersome. Is there a nicer solution?

This is how I initialize & then use sounds:

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
soundPoolMap = new SparseIntArray();
soundPoolMap.put(CLICK_1, soundPool.load(activity, R.raw.click1, 1));
soundPoolMap.put(CLICK_2, soundPool.load(activity, R.raw.click2, 2));
...
float volume = 1.0f;
soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(soundID), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is you want to mute your app when device is on `silent mode`.

Try to check the the `RingerMode` every time before your app play sound/music and play sound only when the ringer `RingerMode` is normal.

Here is the sample code.

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch (audio.getRingerMode())
{
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
    // Device is on Normal mode.
    // you can play music.
    break; 
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
    // Device is on Silent mode.
    // you should not play sound now.
    break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
    // Device is on Vibrate/Meeting mode.
    // you should not play sound but you can make vibrate device (if you want).
    break;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Improved: Always start the playback and control the MediaPlayer volume based on the current RingerMode. also start an audio monitor loop to do the same in case of RingerMode changes during current playback.